# Is there any way to access a specific concept at a particular node in ontology using owlready?

Tags: python, owl, ontology, owlready

I am performing an ontology-based text classification. My ontology is a simple hierarchy of concepts where each subconcept is the result of the upper concept. In the text classification method, I am calculating the cosine similarity between a testing text sample and each node of the ontology where the node with the highest similarity is assigned as the label to the document. The similarity at each node is the normalized mean of the similarities of all nodes below that specific node in the ontology. I am facing difficulty in accessing the nodes (concepts/classes) of ontology to calculate the similarity. I read the Owlready2 documentation but could not find the solution. I have loaded the ontology in .owl format. Since I am new to this topic, it would be great if someone could give me initial guidance or direction so that I can further proceed with this myself.

Another question I have loaded the ontology using this code.

```
onto = get_ontology("C:/fahad/Revision 1/EnvironmentalHazards.owl").load()
```

when I print a class/concept using the following code.

```
print(onto.Scouring)
```

It prints the following.

```
 EnvironmentalHazards.Scouring
```

However, I want to get only "Scouring" as a result so that I can compute its cosine similarity with the text sample. Also, is there any way to print the hierarchy of concepts since the list(onto.classes()) prints only the complete concepts in the ontology and ignores the hierarchy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regarding Q1, it is in the docs explained how to change the rendering of entities: https://pythonhosted.org/Owlready2/annotations.html#custom-rendering-of-entities

Comment: And for Q2, no you have to write your own recursive method which does this - which by the way is trivial. Start form owl:Thing, get subClasses, get their subclasses, etc.

Comment: @UninformedUser Thanks for the quick response. it helped me to solve Q1. But it returns the output as a class 'owlready2.entity.ThingClass', however, I am interested in getting output as string type. Is there any way to convert this to string so that I can use it for computing similarities.

Comment: @UninformedUser for Q2, even if the hierarchy is not considered in owlready2, is there a way to access the class at a particular node/level of the hierarchy. For example, if I don't know the class labels and I want to know the label of a class at the last level of ontology, can I get access to the last level/node using owlready2.

Comment: just iterate over all classes and check for those that do not have a subclass. that's basically all you nedd

Comment: Regarding Q1 I do not understand, having the entity and then calling `entity.name` should return a string

Comment: @UninformedUser I know that we can do that by onto.class.ancestors() or by onto.class.subclasses(), but for that, I need to know the class label. But in my case I just know the level of the hierarchy, for example, I want to know the class labels of classes at level 6 of hierarchy or any other level. Can I do this using owlready. I mean is there any method of indexing through which I can directly get access to a specific level of hierarchy/ontology.

Comment: @UninformedUser yes the documentation says it should return a string, but I am confused why it is not returning a string in my case. Is there any other way to return classes/labels as strings? Thanks for the help and patience.

Comment: no, there is no index for the level. That's why you have to compute the hierarchy by yourself, then you can keep track of the depth in the hierarchy.

Comment: if your dataset has labels, use those. Otherwise you have to extract the local name of the URIs whichis basically the string part after `#` or the last `/`

Comment: @UninformedUser https://pythonhosted.org/Owlready2/annotations.html#custom-rendering-of-entities is not working. Can you provide any other alternative ?